# Installing app on test flight problem integrity could not be valid

Tags: ios, testflight

I uploaded my test flight application today. In the morning everything was ok, but after that I started having problems. The upload was successful, a new version of the application (build) appears, however, when I want to install it, it gives me an error.

Unable to install

This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, intermittent issues all day. Some apps work and others don't.

Apple recently updated their system status page to indicate an issue with Testflight.

> Today, 6:37 PM - ongoing
> Some users are affected

> Users are experiencing a problem with this service. We are working to resolve this issue.

https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

I would assume that the issue gets resolved by itself once they have fixed it on their end.

---

Edit:

It seems to have been resolved, the system status page now says:

> App Store - TestFlight - Resolved Performance
> Yesterday, 6:37 PM - Today, 2:00 AM

> Some users were affected
> Users experienced a problem with this service.

I created and uploaded a new build which now works for our team. All the previous builds seem to work as well.

Comment: @Stefan Did your issue get resolved? If my comment was of any help, please mark my answer as accepted. Otherwise i'd be happy to help if I can.